# check string for specific characters?

Tags: arduino-nano, string

I am just wondering if it is possible to check a string for specific characters.  For example if my string is `String mystr = "test";` and I wanted to check for the letter ***t*** at the beginning and if it is NOT there do something how would I go about this?

I have read about `string.startsWith(string2);` however it returns true or false, I want to be able to do "XYZ" if "ABC" isn't satisfied, and it would seem that `string.contains` isn't a thing.

To paraphrase, I am trying to create an if statement that will evaluate if a string starts with a certain character(s) and will do something if this condition is NOT met.

Comment: In C and C++, the `!` operator means “not”. E.g. `if (!(the condition)) { some_action(); }` means “do some action if the condition is _not_ satisfied”.

Comment: Yes!  I thought that I might be able to adapt the `string.startsWith`, however it flagged saying expected unqualified id before '!' token

Comment: What did you write to get that error? If you don't show us your code, we won't be able to help.

Comment: I messed up and put the `!` in the wrong place, sorry to have not caught that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
if(!actualString.startsWith(expectedString)) {
  // do whatever you have to
}
```

BTW, that is what actually suggested in *@EdgarBonet*'s comment.

Comment: That did it, I had the `!` in the wrong place.